# Is asking whether an article's claims are trustworthy on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should the following question based on this [article](http://arstechnica.co.uk/security/2016/02/the-nsas-skynet-program-may-be-killing-thousands-of-innocent-people/) be on-topic or not?

- Is it true that NSA's Skynet AI program killed thousands of innocent people?

And why?

Comment: That would be on topic over on Skeptics, though :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that question would be on-topic, as it has nothing to do with AI. It is more like a current affairs question.

A relevant question from the article would be maybe about the `limitations/shortcomings behind Skynet's AI program which have caused the disaster`